# SQL Case Statement in Python using multiple dataframe and multiple columns

Tags: sql, python-3.x, pandas

df, df1 and df2 are three data frame, And p0, p1, p2 and rate are columns of df. value belongs to df1 and value_total belongs to df2

i want to do this in pure python or by using pandas.

```
 case

 when (df.p0="ON" and df.p1="OFF") then df1.value*df.rate
 when (df.p1="OFF" and df.p2="OFF") then df2.value_total

 else 0

end as projected_value
```

I tried loc, and np.where also.

Answer (score 1):

Try numpy.select() like so:

```
conditions = [
    (df['p0'] == 'ON') & (df['p1'] == 'OFF'),  # WHEN 1
    (df['p1'] == 'OFF') & (df['p2'] == 'OFF'), # WHEN 2
]
choices = [
    df1['value'] * df['rate'],  # THEN 1
    df2['value_total'],         # THEN 2
]
new_df['projected_value'] = np.select(
    conditions,
    choices,
    default=0,  # ELSE
)
```

Comment: giving this error: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape,

Comment: it is working, when i am doing merge of all data frames and applying the same.

Comment: Are df and df2 different sizes? If so then the first entry in choices will result in an error.